# How to set arc width and arc height in Roundborder

Tags: codenameone

[image: arc width] I want to change arc width and arc height in Roundborder by coding, how to do it in the following code?

```
 RoundBorder roundBorder =     RoundBorder.create().rectangle(true);
  container.getAllStyles().setBorder(roundBorder);
```

Answer (score 0):

The round border always draws a full 180 degree arc from the top line to the bottom line. Due to that constraint the width/height cannot be changed as the lines are fixed into place.

Comment: i want to change width arc as shown in designer theme 
I want to create round border of arc width 10 and arc height 10 . How can it be done by coding not by theme ?

Comment: That is an image border not a `RoundBoder`. Notice that this is a wizard for cutting.  You can use RoundedBorder  (notice the ed) from the `Border` class but it's not quite the same